# How to compute sum of sum with changing upper range

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math

I am implement the function to get the value of W with input is k, epsilon, and Omega. The function W is defined as
[image]

Please don't worry about the complex of equation. It is very easy with three known parameter k, epsilon and Omega. Now, I want to implement it in matlab. However, my problem is how to set the range of first loop with upper range min(g-1,k). Let see my implementation for more detail. Is it correct

```
 function W=getW(k,epsilon,Omega)
 n=ceil((1+epsilon)*k);
 sumIn=0;
 sumOut=0;
 g=2;
 for h=1 :min(n-1,k)    
     for g=2:n
        sumIn=sumIn+(g-h)*getA(k,epsilon,g,Omega)*getT(k,g,h);    
     end
     sumOut=sumOut+sumIn;
 end
 sumOut
end
function A=getA(k,epsilon,g,Omega)
    n=ceil((1+epsilon)*k);
    A=nchoosek(n,g)*(Omega)^g*(1-Omega)^(n-g)
end
function T=getT(k,g,h)
    T=nchoosek(k,h)*getS(g,h)/(k^g);
end
function S=getS(g,h)
    sumSX=0;
    for x=1:h-1
    sumSX=sumSX+(-1)^(x-h+1)*nchoosek(h,x)*x^g;
    end
    S=h^g-sumSX;
end
```

To run it set W=getW(500,0.1,0.02)

Comment: The notation is ambiguous (if not incorrect). In regard to the double-summation formula in the red box: `g` is the running index of the inner summation (therefore a dummy index), how can that appear as a parameter in the range of the outer summation? Are you sure there is no typo there?

Answer (score 1):

I think the condition you're looking for is:

```
min((1+epsilon)*k - 1, k);
```

The `g-1` is supposed to be evaluated after the right hand side loop is done, and take the last value of `g`.

Comment: Thank Chris Eelmaa. The formula is correct. So h will run from 1 to min(g-1,k). For example, if k=500, g=501 then h will run from 1 to 500. Otherwise, k=500, g=400, then h run from 1 to 400. However, don't know how to put the condition it in my code. I think it have check very iteration

Comment: @user8264: Yes, that's what I said. Just use `min(n-1, k)` or what I give you. They are the same.

Comment: I modified as your suggestion. However, It cannot stop

Comment: Did you replace the `for h=1 :min(g-1,k)` with `for h=1 :min(n-1,k)`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. However, based on the explaination of Soild. He said that Matlab don’t check the line with FOR again. So h=1 :min(n-1,k) only run from h=1 to n

Comment: Right, I check the function again. It approximates h from 1 to n. Please check my implementation. Is it correct?

Comment: @user8264: look carefully your code. You are never setting `sumIn` to zero. You should set it to zero after `sumOut=sumOut+sumIn;` is done.

Comment: It seems fine. Are you having any problems?

Comment: If I run with W=getW(500,0.15,0.0165) . It take very very long time. I think it is impossible to converage although it come from journal paper  https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0yxrlfns3dvm26/paperref.pdf?dl=0

Comment: The problem is most likely the `nchoosek` function as that can't be   efficient. It is possible to make it more efficient if you understand how combinations work and how to actually "reuse" the calculated combination results. Plus, if you really think about it, you are re-calculating quite a lot of things that are once calculated.

Comment: Thank sir. Do you have any suggestion for this implementation. The author just give the equation and he did not suggest any way to do it. I think we must consider all case

Comment: @user8264; the easiest way is to define nchoosek recursively and refactor the "factorial finding method" out. You can cache the results. For example: once you calculate 8!, there is no reason to calculate 5! ever again, as you already would have that information if you've calculated 8!. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization Can't help much more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774025/combinations-using-memoization-in-java

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because Matlab don’t check the line with FOR again, at least it does not in the debugger. I guess when Matlab interprets the line `for h=1 :min(g-1,k)` it calculates ones how many times it needs to repeat the loop. In this case it is once because g is 2. Even when g changes it never checks that line again. To avoid this just use while for the outer loop. With

```
function W=getW(k,epsilon,Omega)
n=ceil((1+epsilon)*k);    
sumOut=0;
g=2;
h=1;
while(h <= min(g-1,k))
    sumIn=0;
    for g=2:n
        sumIn=sumIn+(g-h)*getA(k,epsilon,g,Omega)*getT(k,g,h);    
    end
    sumOut=sumOut+sumIn;
    h=h+1;
end

function A=getA(k,epsilon,g,Omega)
    n=ceil((1+epsilon)*k);
    A=nchoosek(n,g)*(Omega)^g*(1-Omega)^(n-g)
end
function T=getT(k,g,h)
    T=nchoosek(k,h)*getS(g,h)/(k^g);
end
function S=getS(g,h)
    sumSX=0;
    for x=1:h-1
        sumSX=sumSX+(-1)^(x-h+1)*nchoosek(h,x)*x^g;
    end
    S=h^g-sumSX;
end
```

Comment: Right. This is I think. I think first sum must use while

Comment: It cannot run dueto g is undefined

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. It is correct now. Let see the my equation again. Is my implementation correct to get A, T, S?

Comment: I don’t understand the equation, but if I had to implement this I would do it the same way you did (just with the while-loop and changes like I posted it).